# Exuberant Ctags for python produces too few tags

Tags: python, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Please consider the following MWE:

```
myGlob = 1

def countMe():
    for i in range(10):
            print(i)

def countMeAgain():
    for i in range(10):
            print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    countMe()
    countMeAgain()
    myGlob = 2
```

*Problem:* When I run `ctags abc.py`, which creates a file called `tag`, and thereafter open `tag`, I just see:

```
print   abc.py  /^            print(i)$/
```

I was expecting to see tags for countMe, countMeAgain and myGlob. Why does this take place?

**What have I tried:** I am using OSX + vim. I installed exuberant ctags using homebrew. OSX has a limited version of ctags by default. Thus, if `/private/etc/paths` gives higher precedence to `/usr/bin` than `/usr/local/bin` (the latter houses the version of ctags obtained from homebrew), then running `ctags abc.py` will use the default version of ctags instead of the homebrew-installed version. I have verified that I am not committing this error.

I learned of this potential error from [Exuberant Ctags on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808781/exuberant-ctags-on-mac) and https://gist.github.com/Overbryd/1669348

---

Cheers

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be with exuberant-ctags, your example works fine for me with Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310.

Comment: 5.9 isn't readily available for Mac...

Comment: responding to myself:  You can build it from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/exuberant-ctags/1:5.9~svn20110310-11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem:

exuberant-ctags is no longer being maintained by its original developer. A new repository is being developed.

I uninstalled my old ctags installation. I then installed from this repository using brew:

https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags

See also [ctags, vim and python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948545/ctags-vim-and-python-code)